# Android Studio project : easier way to create a new activity

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

To create a new Activity I usually follow this procedure :

1.) I create a new Java Class (for exemple : "SecondActivity")

2.) I create a new .xml layout (for exemple : "second_layout")

3.) I copy the "starting code" of MainActivity in SecondActivity.

4.) I replace the name of the Activity and the name of the layout in the new code of "SecondActivity".

The procedure is correct but too long. I would like to know if there is an easier or faster way to do the same operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select Project from left side of your Android Studio IDE, then select app. Under app select Java folder, right click on it. Choose option New followed by Activity and then the type of you activity you want. After clicking on that a window will appear which will ask you to fill in the Activity name and press OK. Your new activity is created. This is the simplest method to create a new activity which I generally follow.

Project -> app -> Java (right click) -> New -> Activity -> Type of Activity -> Enter Name of Activity -> OK

Answer (score 1):

From the Android docs, here's an example:

> In the Project window, right-click the app folder and select New >
>   Activity > Empty Activity. In the Configure Activity window, enter
>   "DisplayMessageActivity" for Activity Name and click Finish (leave all other
>   properties set to the defaults). Android Studio automatically does
>   three things:
>
> 1. List item Creates the DisplayMessageActivity.java file.
> 2. Creates the corresponding activity_display_message.xml layout file.
> 3. Adds the required  element in AndroidManifest.xml.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=en-us